# Access issue on Sp2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are migarting from SP2010 to 2013,
We we try to access the access webpart in 2013 we are receiving the following error.
"This application was designed in a version of Microsoft Access that is not compatible with the version of Access Services 2010 installed on this server. The application must be opened in a compatible version of Microsoft Access and upgraded manually in order to be used on this server. Click Open in Access to open the file in Microsoft Access."